# How to fix cql_filter problem with unicode characters in GeoServer 2.17.2?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, cql-filter, unicode

I am using GeoServer 2.17.2 and OpenLayers v6.4.3, I can not get result when my cql_filter query is consist of unicode characters, I found out this issue can solve by add a code in tomcat server.xml, But I didn't install tomcat therefore I can not use that solution moreover I tried to use encodeURIComponent() but it didn't work also. my query in cql_filter is "province = زنجان" for example, as well as this issue cause to I get cors() error:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.3.0/exceptions_1_3_0.xsd">
<ServiceException> Could not parse CQL filter list. Lexical error at line 1, column 12. Encountered: "\u0632" (1586), after : "" Parsing : province = زنجان. </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

How I can fix this problem?

```
     var cqlWmsLayers=
     new ol.layer.Tile({
         title:`${layerName}`,
           visible: true,
      source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
       url: `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/${workspaceName}/wms`,  
       params: {'LAYERS': `${workspaceName}:${layerName}`,'cql_filter': "province = زنجان" },
 ratio: 1,
        serverType: 'geoserver',
```

OS: Debian 10 x64

Comment: can you add some details about to solve this  "by add a code in tomcat server.xml" and also the relevant part of the GeoServer log file (ideally, at GeoTools-Dev level)

Comment: Do you need single quotes around the province name in the CQL?

Comment: @IanTurton actually I didn't use that solution I mentioned above, because I didn't install tomcat but I found in stackexchange and geoserver users mail

Comment: @Mike which format is correct? I saw that in somewhere in stackexchange, However If you know correct format please let me know, I did many method but didn't get result

Comment: Did you try `"province = 'زنجان'"`, as @Mike mentioned?

Comment: @Mike thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tested this on a local machine and @Mike is correct, the only problem is that you didn't have single quotes (`'`) around the province name, so

```
province = 'زنجان'
```

works fine.

I suspect this is a pointer to a possible problem that CQL expects property names to consist of ASCII characters, but I suspect that may be baked into the standard.

Comment: thank you so much,  did you think this issue return a problem in geoserver or not it because of openlayers software structure, however I hope this issue fix in next version if it is a bug

Comment: the problem isn't a bug, string literals have to have a quote around them to distinguish them from attribute names